# react-date-range picker selects system date instead of moment.timezone date

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-date-range-picker for selecting date ranges.I want to set different timezone(America/Los_Angeles) date for that I'm using moment timezone. .moment().tz() returns correct date. but date range selects system date

```
import { DateRangePicker } from "react-date-range";
import moment from "moment-timezone";
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css'; // theme css file
moment.tz.setDefault("America/Los_Angeles");

function App() {
  const selectionRange = {
    startDate:  moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles'),
    endDate: moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles'),
    key: "selection"
  };
  return (

    <div className="App">
      <DateRangePicker
        ranges={[selectionRange]}
        onChange={ranges => {
          console.log(ranges);
          console.log(selectionRange);
        }}
      ></DateRangePicker>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for those who are looking here is a workaround:

```
const selectionRange = {
    startDate: moment().startOf("day"),
    endDate: moment().endOf("day"),
    key: "selection"
  }

const [rangeDates, setRangeDates] = useState(selectionRange)

const handleOnChange = payload => {
    const { startDate, endDate } = payload.selection

    setRangeDates({
      ...rangeDates,
      startDate: moment(startDate),
      endDate: moment(endDate),
    })
  }

<DateRange
        ranges={[rangeDates]}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      >
```

Thanks to mesvil7 source:
https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range/issues/327#issuecomment-553505978